# Silex routing wildcard

Tags: php, silex

I want to do something like this with Silex:

```
$app->match('/{page?}/{action?}/{part?}/{detail?}', function() {
});
```

So all 4 elements can be there, but it's not needed. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define [default values](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html#default-values) to parameters to make them optional.

Something like this should work:

```
$app->match('/{page}/{action}/{part}/{detail}', function() {
})->value('page', 'home')
->value('action', 'index')
->value('part', 'somePart')
->value('detail', 'someDetail');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$app->get('/{wildcard}', function ($wildcard) use ($app, $shared) {
    // ...
})
->assert('wildcard', '.+')
->value('wildcard', '');
```